# Boto3 unable to read the metadata from the file which contains timestamp in the name

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

i am trying to read the metadata content attached in the file from s3 bucket using boto3

```
key = "myfile_20401__2021-03-04_16:33:12.597"
aws_s3_client=boto3.client("s3")

def get_s3_metadata(key):
    bucket="my_bucket_name"
    s3_client=aws_s3_client()
    s3_response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    metadata = s3_response.get("Metadata")


get_s3_metadata(key)
```

But the above code return following error

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

As analyzed, this was not caused due to the access issue, but due to the file name . so when i removed the time stamp from the file, it works.

so is there any way we can resolve this issue without changing the file name(including the time stamp)?
Appreciated if anybody can help on this?

Comment: try `key = "myfile_20401__2021-03-04_16:33:12.597"` - your key is probably being cut off if that is your exact code

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include a [mre]?  As it is now, it's a syntax error.

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary and Anon, i have update the code in such way that can be reproduceable in the real scenario- (when have aws lambda attached with s3 trigger in this case). i tried with the same way as mentioned -  key = "myfile_20401__2021-03-04_16:33:12.597", but retuning the same error. so does it mean boto3 wont support to read the metadata from such file name ?

Answer (score 0):

Your S3 object key contains characters (the colons), which [aren't safe for use with S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html). Fortunately that's easy to solve, as to use colons you just have to urlencode them:

```py
from urllib.parse import quote
import boto3


def get_s3_metadata(key):
    bucket="my_bucket_name"
    s3_client=boto3.client("s3")
    s3_response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=quote(key))
    metadata = s3_response.get("Metadata")

    
key = "myfile_20401__2021-03-04_16:33:12.597"
get_s3_metadata(key)
```